# Can I use YoutubeAPI to create live events with different user

Tags: c#, api, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

As far as I know, when I developed a console app using YoutubeAPI to create live events for streaming, youtube required me to choose the account which was enable live streaming to put live events on.
But when I developed a website app using that API, even though I opened icognito browser to create live events, it still used my first account in Chrome to create live event.
I wondered if there is some way to make this API to select user like what happened in console app. 
I think it is because of the client_secrets.json but I don't know how to fix it.
I am using C# to develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Live Streaming endpoints require OAuth, you must be authenticated as the user you wish to stream live with.  You cannot stream on another user's behalf unless they have logged in and provided a valid OAuth token to use for your requests.